# Matlab text (with background) in front of axis of a plot

Tags: matlab, text, plot, background, axis

I'm using the text function to add some labels in a Matlab chart, but when it is in front of an axis I can't bring the text (that has a background) to the front.
I tried to use uistack(h, 'top') with o success.

The code i'm using is:

```
texto_last=strcat(num2str(yy(end-i,1),'%.2f'));
hhhh=text(2*xx(end-i,1)-xx(end-i-2,1),yy(end-i,1),texto_last,'VerticalAlignment'‌​,'bottom',... 'FontSize',8, 'BackGround', 'y','Color','r');
uistack(hhhh, 'top')
```

and the result [postimg.org/image/dnsn96yrd](http://postimg.org/image/dnsn96yrd)

Any suggestion?

Thank you

---

Edit (2):

Here is my code:

```
load('test_error.mat')
%% PLOTA
hFig=figure('Color',[1 1 1],'Units','centimeters','Position', [2 2 28.7+2 21+2]);
[AX,H1,H2] =plotyy(xx,yy,xx,yy);
%% MUDA COR
set(H1,'color','k');
set(H2,'color','k');
set(AX,{'ycolor'},{'k';'k'}) ;
set(AX,'Position',[0.07 0.1 0.86 0.8]) ;
%% GRID
grid minor
grid on
%% LEGENDA
index_name=find(strcmp(name_matrix(:,1), ticker));
legenda=strcat(ticker, {' - '}, name_matrix(index_name,2));
legend(legenda,'Location','southoutside','Orientation','horizontal')
%% ULTIMO DADO
verifica=isnan(yy(end,1));
i=0;
while verifica==1
    i=i+1;
    verifica=isnan(yy(end-i,1)); 
end
texto_last=strcat(num2str(yy(end-i,1),'%.2f'));
hhhh=text(1.01,((yy(end-i,1)-min(ylim)))/(max(ylim)-min(ylim)),texto_last,'VerticalAlignment','bottom',...
     'FontSize',8, 'BackGround', 'y','Color','k','Units','normalized');
uistack(hhhh, 'top')
%% DATA DA ULTIMA ATUALIZACAO
s=strcat({'Last update: '},datestr(xx(end-i,1),'dd-mmm-yyyy'));
annotation('textbox', ...
[0.77 0.88 0.2 0.06],...
'String', s,'EdgeColor','none',...
'HorizontalAlignment','center','VerticalAlignment','middle','FontSize',8)
%% FORMATA DATA
datetick('x','mmm-yy','keepticks');
rotateXLabels( gca, 90)
%% MINOR TICKS
set(gca,'XMinorTick','on','YMinorTick','on')
```

Note that I use the function rotateXLabels that can be found:
*** I cant post the link because of my reputation, but just google for rotatexlabels ***

And the data I uploaded at:
http://1drv.ms/1KrymDx

Thank you

Comment: That should work. Please post a runnable example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @ranthero Unfortunately, I have no advice. For me it works fine, Windows 7, Matlab 2014b. Please provide code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ranthero have you tried to move `uistack(hhhh, 'top')` to the bottom of the code?

Comment: @patrik Yes, added to the bottom and nothing change.